# Flutter TextFormField direction

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-textformfield

TextField direction is rtl or ltr only for all lines
in note apps the field detection every line direction how can i do that?

i try some modules to auto detection but if the line 1 have ar language the direction will be rtl and if line 2 have en language the direction for all lines will be ltr

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
new Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: TextField(
     textAlign: TextAlign.right,
     controller: _textEdittingControler_bookName,
     autofocus: true,
     decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: "label Text",
                hintText: "hint Text"
                ),
     )
```

For more info https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html

Comment: this widget also take one direction for all lines, i working in note app so in the normal of notes apps the text field for line by line the field detect the direction for the line 
u know how i can do that?